# Matrices Null Space

Tags: matrices

We know that $A\begin{pmatrix}1\\ 2\\ 3\\ 4\\ 5\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}2\\ -2\\ -2\\ \ 2\end{pmatrix}$ and $A\begin{pmatrix}5\\ 4\\ 3\\ 2\\ 1\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}-6\\ 6\\ 6\\ \ -6\end{pmatrix}$

$Ax= s\begin{pmatrix}-1\\ 1\\ 1\\ \ -1\end{pmatrix}$ $s$ being any real number

How can I calculate the dimension of $Null(A)$ with this information
We cannot calculate $A$ right?

Answer (score 1):

Let $U=\begin{pmatrix}-1\\ 1\\ 1\\ \ -1\end{pmatrix}$.

The second indication says that $Im(A)=\mathbb{R}U$.

Thus, by the rank-nullity theorem, the dimension of the kernel is :

$$dim(Ker(A))=5-dim(Im(A))=5-1=4.$$

Oddly, we do not need the first relationships for this conclusion.

Comment: why is dim(Im(A)) equal to the range of the matrix?

Comment: You mean the "rank" of the matrix ?